# Copiar string a partir de uma posição

Tags: c#

Tenho isso:

```
private List<string> _listaCommiter()
        {
            string s = string.Empty;
            string _start = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dir_inicio"];
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            List<string> tes = new List<string>();

            string path = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Caminho_Commiter"];

            string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            string texto = string.Empty;

            foreach (var item in arquivos)
            {
                s = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item);
                int _int = item.ToString().IndexOf(_start);
                texto = item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length);

                if (!item.Contains("TSNMVC"))
                    lista.Add(s);
            }

            return lista;
        }
```

No momento em que eu monto a variável texto dentro do foreach, me dá esse erro:

> Message=O índice e o comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da
>   cadeia de caracteres. Nome do parâmetro: length

Abaixo todo a mensagem de erro

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=O índice e o comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da
>   cadeia de caracteres. Nome do parâmetro: length   Source=mscorlib
>   ParamName=length   StackTrace:
>          em System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>          em CriandoExtraindo_ZIP.Form1._listaCommiter() na c:\Projetos_Amil\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\Form1.cs:linha
>   211
>          em CriandoExtraindo_ZIP.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na
>   c:\Projetos_Amil\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\Form1.cs:linha
>   240
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          em CriandoExtraindo_ZIP.Program.Main() na c:\Projetos_Amil\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\CriandoExtraindo_ZIP\Program.cs:linha
>   19
>          em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Comment: No debug, o que tem dentro de `_int` e `item` antes do erro?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, _int tem a posição em que eu quero remontar a nova string, que no primeiro caso é 13. Item é um array com os nomes dos arquivos que quero manipular´Isso está correto.

Comment: Tem certeza? Se estivesse, não estaria dando erro. Coloque um *breakpoint* em `texto = item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length);` e confira item a item.

Comment: Quando chega a texto = ... eu não consigo mais andar, pois é aí que dá o erro, mas em item sim, está correto conforme eu disse acima.

Comment: Existe uma aba no Visual Studio chamada `Watch 1`. Jogue o conteúdo da linha lá e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Esse é a primeira passada de item: `C:\Teste_Zip\web\ace\ace003c.asp`

Comment: em cima dessa linha texto = ...., está dando isso no watch1: `texto = item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length); 'item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' string`

Comment: Fiz na mão e deu o mesmo erro. Fiz assim: `string s1 = @"C:\Teste_Zip\web\ace\ace003c.asp";
            int _n = s1.IndexOf(_start);
            string s2 = s1.Substring(_n, s1.Length);`

Comment: Nas linhas de baixo, coloque `_int` em uma e `item` em outra. Veja o resultado.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, não entendi o que vc quer dizer com nas "linhas de baixo"

Comment: Deu certo assim: `texto = item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length-_int);`.

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro ocorre porque você esta tentando recupera uma parte da String que não existe.

Veja o caso

```
String item = "0123456789"; // o Length da sua String é 10;
int _int = 3; // inicio da Substring = 3

var texto = item.ToString().Substring(_int, item.Length);
```

Quando você faz isso você esta removendo a parte da `String` começando na posição 3 e terminando na 10ª posição, ou seja o resultado da sua `String` seria algo entre a 3ª e a 13ª posição da `String`, mas sua `String` só tem 10 posições.

Logo você terá a mensagem

> Message=O índice e o comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da
>   cadeia de caracteres. Nome do parâmetro: length

```
using System;

 public class Sample
 {
    public static void Main () {
       Cordas myString = "abc";
       bool test1 = myString.Substring (2, 1) .Equals ( "C"); // Isso é verdade.
       Console.WriteLine (test1);
       bool test2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty (myString.Substring (3, 0)); // Isso é verdade.
       Console.WriteLine (test2);
       try {
          cadeia str3 = myString.Substring (3, 1); // Isto lança ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
          Console.WriteLine (str3);
       }
       catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) {
          Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
       }         
    }
 }
 // O exemplo mostra o seguinte resultado:
 // Verdade
 // Verdade
 // Índice e comprimento devem se referir a um local dentro da cadeia.
 // Nome do parâmetro: comprimento
```

Mais Detalhes [Aqui](https://translate.google.com.br/translate?hl=pt-BR&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fpt-br%2Flibrary%2Faka44szs(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&anno=2).