# Erro ao remontar uma string. Tamanho está fora

Tags: c#, .net, string

Não consigo preencher essa lista, da forma como está:

```
foreach (var item in text)
            {
                string[] linha = item.Split('\n');
                foreach (var i in linha)
                {
                    string nova_string = i.Substring(0, i.LastIndexOf("\r"));
                    lista.Add(nova_string);                    
                }                
            }
```

Está dando esse erro:

> Comprimento não pode ser menor que zero. Nome do parâmetro: length

Comment: [Possível duplicata](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115877/copiar-string-a-partir-de-uma-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o/115909#115909)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão  `i.LastIndexOf("\r")` não está achando o caractere procurado. Quando o que está sendo pesquisado dentro da *string* não é achado o retorno deste método é -1, conforme [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_).

Então só pode usar o resultado dele se puder garantir que a o que procura existe. Precisa usar um comando `if` ou o operador condicional `? :` para decidir o que fazer, ou que resultado retornar quando o texto não existir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).